# In mysql query with like statement

Tags: mysql, sql

In MYSQL I created the following query:

```
    select product_name as name  from product_table where
product_name not in ('a', 'b', 'c') 
    and  upper(product_name) like upper('_%')
```

this query returns all the product names :(
I don't want it to return all the product names !

Comment: Post a sample of the data in `product_name`. As written, your query would return all rows except `'a','b','c'` with one or more character. If `'a','b','c'` are not present, it would return all rows.

Comment: And if not all, what _do_ you want the query to return?

Comment: I don't have a product name which starts with '_' and this query returns all the products!

Comment: You know that `_` is a wildcard character which matches one character? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like If you want a literal `_` you need to escape it as `\_`

Answer (score 0):

What you've asked for there is a list of all product names that are not 'a', 'b', or 'c'.  upper(product_name) will always match upper('_%')

_ matches any one character
% matches one or more characters

so anything consisting of one or more characters will be returned not including 'a', 'b', or 'c'.